# Input value is being null laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I am using following parameter value to be posted into controller but it shows `null`

```
Route::get('JobApplication/{JobId}','JobApplicationController@view');
Route::post('application/','JobApplicationController@Post');
```

In `view` method of `JobApplicationController` value is `null` when I try to get it as:

```
$JobId  = Input::get('JobId') ;
```

Comment: You can access the `JobId` in the request object using this syntax `request()->JobId`

Comment: The `{JobId}` is a route segment, not an input value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$JobId= $request->JobId; or view($JobId){echo $JobId}
```

Comment: I need it in post method not view

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function Post($JobId) {
   return $JobID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `JobID` as route segment, so you can access it directly as a parameter to the method.

```
<?php

class JobApplicationController
{
    public function view($jobId)
    {
        dd($jobId);
    }
}
```

The code `$JobId  = Input::get('JobId');` that you are trying is used in situations where `JobId` is sent as a query parameter, such as in url https://example.com/JobApplication?JobId=12321